# The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, migration, visual-studio-2019

I installed all necessary packages, but after making first migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

I got error  CS0234 The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Then I reinstalled Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and everything was fine, zero errors in editor, but after trying to make migration again I got the same error.

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing other versions of EntityFrameworkCore. packages (3.1.10 - 3.1.11)

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.